# insert from temptable to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I wish to add data from temp table to another table but its giving me Duplicate Value Error.
I think its because for other client  may have same primary key(statement_image_id is primary Key) or same primary key for same client but different LOAN No.

Now how can I add these data to another table.

**My Temp table:**

```
select top 0 * into #temptable from tab1 
INSERT INTO #temptable ([STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID]
     ,[client_no]
      ,[LOAN_NO]
      ,[statement_date] 
      ,[ACCRUED_LATE_CHARGES]
      ,[TOTAL_DUE])

      SELECT msp.[STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID] --as msp_ID
     ,[client_no]
      ,[LOAN_NO]
      ,[statement_date] 
      ,[ACCRUED_LATE_CHARGES]
      ,[TOTAL_DUE]

      FROM tab1 si, tab2 msp
  WHERE msp.[client_no] = si.[client_no] and  msp.[loan_no] = si.[loan_no] 
  and  msp.[statement_date] = si.[statement_date]
  and msp.[statement_image_id] <> si.[statement_image_id]
```

and this is what I tried .

First is giving duplicate error and other is not allowed I think.

**First**

```
 insert into tab1  select * from #temptable
```

**Second**

```
insert into tab1   select * from #temptable
where tab1.[client_no] =#temptable.client_no
and  tab1.[loan_no]= #temptable.[loan_no]
and tab1.[statement_date] = #temptable.[STATEMENT_DATE]
```

Any Suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `duplicate\null` values in the `primary key` columns.

One thing you can do is,
Update `tab1` for same `STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID` values in `tab1 and #temptable`.

Insert data into `tab1` for diffrent `STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID` values in `tab1 and #temptable`.

```
insert into tab1 (
  select tmp.* 
  from #temptable tmp
  join tab1 t on t.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID != tmp.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID
) as x

update tab1 t
  join #temptable tmp on t.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID == tmp.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID
set 
  t.client_no = tmp.client_no,
  t.LOAN_NO = tmp.LOAN_NO,
  t.statement_date = tmp.statement_date, 
  t.ACCRUED_LATE_CHARGES = tmp.ACCRUED_LATE_CHARGES,
  t.TOTAL_DUE = tmp.TOTAL_DUE;
```

**Note:**
If any other columns have `unique` `constraint` you have to consider that also.

If you cannot loose data then create a new `image_id`

```
insert into tab1 (
  select tmp.* 
  from #temptable tmp
  join tab1 t on t.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID != tmp.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID
  union all
  select 
    UUID(),
    tmp.client_no,
    tmp.LOAN_NO,
    tmp.statement_date,
    tmp.ACCRUED_LATE_CHARGES,
    tmp.TOTAL_DUE
  from #temptable tmp
  join tab1 t on t.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID == tmp.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID
) as x
```

note: if `UUID()` is your choice.. else `some_new_id`.

Comment: but then I will loose all the data for  t.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID == tmp.STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID. It is possible that other client need other details.Any alternate solution.Should I alter this imageid before inserting somehow